# How to create an SqlConnection in C# to point to UDL file

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I have a .udl (Universal data link) file in my project. Now I want to create an SQL Connection that should point to this particular file. SqlConnection object expects a connection string, how can we build an SqlConnection using .UDL file?

Comment: From MSDN site:

It is possible to supply connection information for an OleDbConnection in a Universal Data Link (UDL) file; however you should avoid doing so. UDL files are not encrypted, and expose connection string information in clear text. Because a UDL file is an external file-based resource to your application, it cannot be secured using the .NET Framework. UDL files are not supported for SqlClient.

Have a look here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/0bb40f32-86f4-4b6f-a2e0-bc2bdcf07b63

Comment: thanks @Ademar, post this as an answer, and I will mark it.

Comment: Thanks @Nirman, will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN site:

> It is possible to supply connection information for an OleDbConnection
>   in a Universal Data Link (UDL) file; however you should avoid doing
>   so. UDL files are not encrypted, and expose connection string
>   information in clear text. Because a UDL file is an external
>   file-based resource to your application, it cannot be secured using
>   the .NET Framework. UDL files are not supported for SqlClient.

Have a look here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/0bb40f32-86f4-4b6f-a2e0-bc2bdcf07b63

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to convert OleDBConnection to SQLConnection.

```
private static string CONNECTION_NAME = "\\conection.udl";

 private static SqlConnection CreateSqlConnection(OleDbConnection udlInfo)
        {
            try
            {   
                string CONNECTION_STRING = $"Database={udlInfo.Database};Server={udlInfo.DataSource};Integrated Security=True;connect timeout = 30";
                var connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
                connection.Open();
                return connection;
            } catch
            {
                 Console.WriteLine($"{CONNECTION_NAME} Not found");

                return null;
            }

        }

public static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
        {
            var udlInfo = new OleDbConnection($"File Name={Application.StartupPath}{CONNECTION_NAME}");

            return CreateSqlConnection(udlInfo);
        }
```