# Use UDL for SqlConnection connection string values

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

Through the information I have found searching here on stackoverflow, I have what I think is 90% of this solved but because of how OleDbConnection is converted to define SqlConnection, the call to the class with the connection and test script wants definition I am unsure how to provide.

I've used these pages to get what I have so far

[How to create an SqlConnection in C# to point to UDL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234370/how-to-create-an-sqlconnection-in-c-sharp-to-point-to-udl-file)

[Calling an SQL Connection method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793266/calling-an-sql-connection-method-in-c-sharp)

```
    private static string CONNECTION_NAME = @"C:\Temp\DisplayDB.udl";

    public static class MyConnection
    {
        public static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
        {
            var udlInfo = new OleDbConnection($"File Name={CONNECTION_NAME}");

            return CreateSqlConnection(udlInfo);
        }

        public static SqlConnection CreateSqlConnection(OleDbConnection udlInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                string CONNECTION_STRING = $"Database={udlInfo.Database};Server={udlInfo.DataSource};User ID=User;Password=13245;Integrated Security=True;connect timeout = 30";
                var connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
                connection.Open();
                return connection;

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{CONNECTION_NAME} Not found");

                return null;
            }

        }
    }

    private void DBCheck()
    {

    // The line below is my issue, mouseover error of ".CreateSqlConnection" 
    // says there is no argument given that corresponds to the required
    // formal parameter 'udlInfo' of
    // 'MainWindow.MyConnection.CreateSqlConnection(OleDbConnection)'

        using (var con = MyConnection.CreateSqlConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand("IF DB_ID ('CodeTest') IS NULL " +
                         "BEGIN " +
                         "USE MASTER " +
                         "CREATE DATABASE CodeTest" +
                         " END", con);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

I expect the WPF to use the Database and Server from the UDL file to make the SqlConnection so I can run queries and commands.  I understand the security part of UDL in plain text but I do not want hard coded values as this application will be used in various environments nor do I want those values to need definition on each launch of the app.

Comment: `var con = MyConnection.GetSqlConnection()`?

Comment: thats what i found in this link for how to call the class in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793266/calling-an-sql-connection-method-in-c-sharp